# Estimate parameters using R code of a dataset

Tags: r, parameters, dataset

Suppose I have a data set. There are some categorical variables and some numerical variables. I want to estimate the parameters of a model `$y=exp(X'b)$` for every categories and others. I am trying to do it in **R** code. But there are some errors.

```
sex <- c("F","M","F","M","F")
age <- c(20,30,23,32,25) 
dat <- data.frame(sex,age)
myfun <- function(par, data){

         xx <- data
         func <- exp(par[1]*xx$age+par[2]*factor(xx$sex))
         return(-func)
}

optim(myfun, par=c(0.1,0.4), data=dat)
```

Comment: There are a few issues here. First, you probably want `as.numeric` instead of `factor`. Second, you're returning a vector of length `nrow(dat)`, but `optim` only optimizes functions that return 1-dimensional vectors. What is the function you're trying to optimize?

Comment: Yes I understand the fact. But want to estimate for other categories make one category as a reference category (e.g. variable education (primary, secondary, higher, others)). If I want to estimate parameters for education variable with considering one category as a reference category then what can I do? My concern is there.

Comment: My function is f(x)=exp(X'b). @josilber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps? This will do Maximum Likelihood Estimation. The reason you were getting errors was because optim() doesn't work with categorical variables, and you need to take the negative sum of the log-likelihood function (for MLE).

```
sex <- c("F","M","F","M","F")
age <- c(20,30,23,32,25) 
dat <- data.frame(sex,age)
myfun <- function(par, x1,x2){

    -sum(log(exp(par[1]*x1+par[2]*x2)))
}
optim(myfun, par=c(0.1,0.4), x1=dat$age,x2=as.numeric(dat$sex))

$par
[1] 21.916058  4.234422
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working. Code as.numeric() makes one category 0 and other 1. But which one category of sex is 0 or 1?

Comment: Starts left and moves right, assigning each new level a number incremented by one. F = 0 and M = 1